# Magento index problem while product save in backend

Tags: magento-1.5

I'm getting the following error while saving products in backend:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`chia`.`mage_index_process_event`, CONSTRAINT `FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT` FOREIGN KEY (`process_id`) REFERENCES `index_process` (`process_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I'm using magento version 1.5.

I tried truncating these tables 'index_process', 'index_process_event' and 'index_event' and saved product but again the same error occurred. I'm not getting what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.
Take database backup before working.

> 1)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `index_process_event`;  
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
`index_event`;  
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `index_process`;
```

> 2)

CREATE TABLE `index_event` ( 
    `event_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `type` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    `entity` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    `entity_pk` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    `old_data` MEDIUMTEXT, 
    `new_data` MEDIUMTEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`), 
    UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UNIQUE_EVENT` (`type`,`entity`,`entity_pk`) 
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

```
    CREATE TABLE `index_process` (
`process_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`indexer_code` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`status` ENUM('pending','working','require_reindex') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
`started_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
`ended_at` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
`mode` ENUM('real_time','manual') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'real_time',
PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IDX_CODE` (`indexer_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

> 3)

```
INSERT INTO `index_process`(`process_id`,`indexer_code`,`status`,`started_at`,`ended_at`,`mode`) VALUES (1,'catalog_product_attribute','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(2,'catalog_product_price','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(3,'catalog_url','pending','2010-02-13 19:12:15','2010-02-13 19:12:15','real_time'),(4,'catalog_product_flat','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(5,'catalog_category_flat','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(6,'catalog_category_product','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(7,'catalogsearch_fulltext','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time'),(8,'cataloginventory_stock','pending','2010-02-13 00:00:00','2010-02-13 00:00:00','real_time');

    CREATE TABLE `index_process_event` (
`process_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`event_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`status` ENUM('new','working','done','error') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`,`event_id`),
KEY `FK_INDEX_EVNT_PROCESS` (`event_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_INDEX_EVNT_PROCESS` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `index_event` (`event_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT` FOREIGN KEY (`process_id`) REFERENCES `index_process` (`process_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```